# Update UDP checksum in fragmented packets

Tags: networking, udp, checksum, nat, ip-fragmentation

I'm building a network appliance. I need to support NAT and IP packet fragmentation. When I change the source or destination address of a UDP packet, I have to correct the UDP checksum (and the IP checksum too, but that's trivial). When the packet is fragmented, I'd have to collect all the fragments to recalculate the checksum. I know the old address and the new address. I'd like to:

1. Un-negate the checksum
2. Subtract the old address
3. Add the new address
4. Re-reduce the sum and negate

This process doesn't always work. Is there any way to update the checksum versus having to recalculate it from scratch?

I've tried:

```
long CalcCheckSumAdd(unsigned char *pbHeader, int iSize, long lInitial){

    long lSum = lInitial;

    while (iSize > 1){

        lSum += *((unsigned short*)pbHeader);

        pbHeader += 2;

        iSize -= 2;

    }

    if (iSize > 0) lSum += *pbHeader;

    return lSum;

}

long CalcCheckSumSubract(unsigned char *pbHeader, int iSize, long lInitial){

    long lSum = lInitial;

    while (iSize > 1){

        lSum -= *((unsigned short*)pbHeader);

        pbHeader += 2;

        iSize -= 2;

    }

    if (iSize > 0) lSum -= *pbHeader;

    return lSum;

}

unsigned short CalcCheckSumFinish(long lSum){

    while (lSum >> 16){

        lSum = (lSum & 0xFFFF) + (lSum >> 16);

    }

    return (unsigned short)(~lSum);

}

long CalcCheckSumUnfinish(unsigned short usSum){

    // Can't totally undo lossy finish logic

    return ~usSum;

}

unsigned short CalcCheckSumUpdateAddress(unsigned short usOldSum, unsigned long ulOldAddress, unsigned long ulNewAddress){

    long lSumFixed = CalcCheckSumUnfinish(usOldSum);

    lSumFixed = CalcCheckSumSubract((unsigned char*)&ulOldAddress,sizeof(ulOldAddress),lSumFixed);

    lSumFixed = CalcCheckSumAdd((unsigned char*)&ulNewAddress,sizeof(ulNewAddress),lSumFixed);

    return CalcCheckSumFinish(lSumFixed);

}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT: Added unit test code below**

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long CalcCheckSumAdd(unsigned char *pbHeader, int iSize, long lInitial){

    long lSum = lInitial;

    while (iSize > 1){

        lSum += *((unsigned short*)pbHeader);

        pbHeader += 2;

        iSize -= 2;

    }

    if (iSize > 0) lSum += *pbHeader;

    return lSum;

}

unsigned short CalcCheckSumFinish(long lSum){

    while (lSum >> 16){

        lSum = (lSum & 0xFFFF) + (lSum >> 16);

    }

    return (unsigned short)(~lSum);

}

void Randomize(unsigned char *pucPacket, unsigned long ulSize){

    for (unsigned long ulByte = 0; ulByte < ulSize; ulByte++){

        pucPacket[ulByte] = (unsigned char)(255 * rand() / RAND_MAX);

    }

}

unsigned short Calc(unsigned char *pucPacket, unsigned long ulSize){

    long lSum = CalcCheckSumAdd(pucPacket,ulSize,0);

    return CalcCheckSumFinish(lSum);

}

unsigned short Fix(unsigned short usOrig, unsigned int uiOld, unsigned int uiNew){

    // TODO: Replace this with something that makes main never fail
    usOrig -= uiOld & 0xffff;
    usOrig -= uiOld >> 16 & 0xffff;
    usOrig += uiNew & 0xffff;
    usOrig += uiNew >>16 & 0xffff;

    return usOrig;

}

void Break(unsigned char *pucPacket, unsigned int *puiOld, unsigned int *puiNew){

    unsigned int *puiChange = (unsigned int*)pucPacket;

    *puiOld = *puiChange;

    Randomize((unsigned char*)puiNew,sizeof(unsigned int));

    *puiChange = *puiNew;

}

void PrintBuffer(const char *szName, unsigned char *pucBuff, unsigned int uiSize){

    printf("%s: ",szName);

    for (unsigned int uiByte = 0; uiByte < uiSize; uiByte++){

        printf("%02X",(unsigned int)pucBuff[uiByte]);

    }

    printf("\n");

}

void PrintTestCase(unsigned char *pucOrig, unsigned char *pucChanged, unsigned int uiSize, unsigned short usOrig, unsigned short usChanged, unsigned short usFixed){

    PrintBuffer("Original Buffer",pucOrig,uiSize);
    PrintBuffer("Changed Buffer ",pucChanged,uiSize);

    printf("Orig    checksum: %04X\n",(unsigned int)usOrig);
    printf("Changed checksum: %04X\n",(unsigned int)usChanged);
    printf("Fixed   checksum: %04X\n",(unsigned int)usFixed);

}

int main(){

    srand((unsigned int)time(nullptr));

    unsigned char pucDataOrig[100];
    unsigned char pucDataChanged[100];

    bool bTestFailed = false;

    while (!bTestFailed){

        Randomize(pucDataOrig,sizeof(pucDataOrig));

        memcpy(pucDataChanged,pucDataOrig,sizeof(pucDataOrig));

        unsigned short usOrig = Calc(pucDataOrig,sizeof(pucDataOrig));

        unsigned int uiOld = 0,
                     uiNew = 0;

        Break(pucDataChanged,&uiOld,&uiNew);

        unsigned short usFixed = Fix(usOrig,uiOld,uiNew);

        unsigned short usChanged = Calc(pucDataChanged,sizeof(pucDataChanged));

        if (usChanged == usFixed){

            printf(".");

        }else{

            printf("\nTest case failed\n");
            PrintTestCase(pucDataOrig,pucDataChanged,sizeof(pucDataOrig),usOrig,usChanged,usFixed);

            bTestFailed = true;

        }

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Fragmentation and reassembly should happen at layer-3 and be transparent to layer-4. I really don't see the need to recalculate the UDP checksum due to fragmentation. Fragmentation should happen after NAT, as a packet exits a router, at the exit interface, and the layer-4 checksum should already have been recalculated and updated.

Comment: @RonMaupin My appliance receives the fragmented UDP packet. It then has to NAT it. You can't change the source or destination address of an IP/UDP packet without recalculating/updating the UDP checksum because the UDP checksum includes the sudo-header which includes the IP source and destination addresses. Routers have to do the same thing.

Comment: Routers do not reassemble fragmented packets, that is the job of the receiving host. The current trend today, is that routers and firewalls are configured to not even accept packet fragments (except the first fragment).

Comment: This is from RFC 791: "_The basic internet service is datagram oriented and provides for the fragmentation of datagrams at gateways, with reassembly taking place at the destination internet protocol module in the destination host._"

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm not trying reassemble the packet. I'm trying to change the source address of the packet. Since the packet is IP/UDP I need to recalculate the UDP checksum. I need all the fragments in order to recalculate the UDP checksum, I'd like to avoid needing to collect the fragments and just do a little math to update the checksum instead of recalculating it. Most routers will send an ICMP message back to the host for TCP based fragmentation. For UDP, routers don't have to do much to support fragmentation (unless they are doing NAT). The Cisco 2911 I have supports IP/UDP fragmentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the solution above works only on some cases, but I have a new implem that works for all kind of packet (fragmented or not, UDP, TCP, IP). Here is the implem:

```
/* incremental checksum update */
static inline void
cksum_update(uint16_t *csum, uint32_t from, uint32_t to)
{
    uint32_t sum, csum_c, from_c, res, res2, ret, ret2;

    csum_c = ~((uint32_t)*csum);
    from_c = ~from;
    res = csum_c + from_c;
    ret = res + (res < from_c);

   res2 = ret + to;
   ret2 = res2 + (res2 < to);

   sum = ret2;
   sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
   sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
   *csum = (uint16_t)~sum;

}
```

You can now use this function when you translated you packet address and before sending:

```
/* Update L4 checksums on all packet a part from [2nd, n] fragment */
switch (IS_FRAG(ipv4_hdr) ? 0 : ipv4_hdr->next_proto_id) {
case IPPROTO_TCP:
{
    struct tcp_hdr *tcp_hdr = tcp_header(pkt);

    /* Compute TCP checksum using incremental update */
    cksum_update(&tcp_hdr->cksum, old_ip_addr, *address);
    break;
}
case IPPROTO_UDPLITE:
case IPPROTO_UDP:
{
    struct udp_hdr *udp_hdr = udp_header(pkt);

    /* Compute UDP checksum using incremental update */
    cksum_update(&udp_hdr->dgram_cksum, old_ip_addr, *address);
    break;
}
default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: Does this formula working for you? I am receiving different than expected result
Maybe there us an error in it?
Can You assist? Thx

Answer (score 0):

You have to substract the old ip address and add the new one on the udp checksum, here is the pseudo code:

```
udp_hdr->dgram_cksum -= old_ipv4_addr & 0xffff;
udp_hdr->dgram_cksum -= old_ipv4_addr >> 16 & 0xffff;
udp_hdr->dgram_cksum += new_ipv4_addr & 0xffff;
udp_hdr->dgram_cksum += new_ipv4_addr >>16 & 0xffff;
```

That should handle UDP checksum on IP fragments.

Comment: Thanks for trying but your solution does not work. The problem with this is it doesn't take into account how the checksum is reduced after all the words are added up. I've added some unit test code if you want to test any other ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the packet size/content, this approach can work. It just doesn't always work.